# Отследить событие печать в Javascript / JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, печать

Приветствую!

Мне нужно отследить событие печати в окне браузера в клиентском JS/JQ. Например: пользователь выбирает печать (к примеру с помощью Adobe Reader) и при нажатии переходит на новое окно браузера, где собственно выходит страница на печать, настройки принтера и тд. стандартное окно Адобе. Возможно ли отследить событие печати именно при нажатии на "Печать" в этом окне Адобе из клиентского JS/JQ, т.е. именно при нажатии и непосредственного пуска документа на принтер?

Я пытался использовать этот [ресурс](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/), но этот скрипт работает только при нажатии CTRL+P в окне, а не в случае кнопки для печати на сайте. Нужно отследить именно конкретный факт печати, а не открытия окна Adobe.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Доступа к стандартному окну печати у JS нет. Можно только стилями поменять внешний вид, не более.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению (а может и к счастью), отследить данное событие возможности нет, так как контекст исполнения JavaScript и программа печати (или плагин браузера, смотря что вызывается) это абсолютно разные вещи, не имеющие друг с другом ничего общего.